# Using Nokia Lumia as Dashboard Camera - how much can I record?

Tags: video, nokia-lumia-820

Rather than buy a dash camera I was wondering if my Nokia Lumia can substitute for one. It's an 820 so it can take an SD card, I've got a 32gb one to already in, and I've set new video to be recorded onto the card. I also have a windscreen mount.

How much video am I likely to be able to record with the phone on the standard settings and are there any settings I should use to optimise for this purpose?

Comment: Are you asking about the mounting, or how much time you'll get on a 32Gb card?

Comment: I meant how much time, sorry, I thought it was obvious

Answer (score 2):

I don't own a Lumia 820 but this calculation shown be a good guide for how much time you can record.

According to the [Lumia 820 specs on the Nokia website](http://www.nokia.com/global/products/phone/lumia820/specifications/#), the main camera records at `1080p` with a frame rate of `30 fps`. I assume these are the "standard settings" that you refer to.

Assumptions: compression ratio for the video recorded is `60:1`

Calculation:

```
Frame size K = ( [Pixel Width x Pixel Height x Bit Depth] / 8 ) / 1024
K = ( [1920 x 1080 x 24] / 8 ) / 1024 = 6075 KB / frame
6075 KB/frame x 30 frames/sec = 182250 KB/sec
182250 KB/sec  /  60 compression ratio = 3037.5 KB/s compressed
3037.5 KB/sec compressed * 60 s / min * 1 MB / 1024 KB = 177.98 MB / min
32 GB * (1024 MB / GB) / 177.98 MB / min = 184 minutes
```

So there you have it, **approximately 184 minutes of HD video with 32 GB of storage.**

Hope this helps.

Space saving tip: sync your videos to a PC whenever you have a chance.

[Some of the calculation metrics were borrowed from a similar calculation made for iPhones.](http://whenwillapple.com/blog/2011/10/05/with-the-iphone-4s-improved-camera-and-1080p-hd-video-should-i-go-32gb-or-64gb/)

Answer (score 0):

For security purposes only, you can delete recorded video files if accidents did not occur and start recording all over again. Of course it´s possible to upload to cloud storage or save vids into any mass media device.

Comment: This is not really what the OP asked. He wants to know how much video footage can be stored on his phone at a time - of course he can delete the videos later.